# Getting Compile Error: User-defined type not defined when working to make an old 32-bit template into a Word 2012 64-bit template

Tags: vba, templates, compiler-errors, 32bit-64bit, ms-word

I have a Photo Template that grabs photos from files and places them in their individual boxes in a word document. The file use to be a Word 2003 32-bit file that would only run in our old computer.

I have transformed the file to 64-bit to use in our new computers and saved it as a word-macro-enabled template.
This eliminated a bunch of problems I was having but the last bit is... at first it showed *ambiguous name detected* but after it shut down and restarted it started showing *Compile Error: User-defined type not defined* highlighting the first line of the code below and I can't find a solution after much research.
Please help, I really need this macro to work

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Function SHBrowseForFolder Lib "shell32.dll" (ByRef lpbi As BROWSEINFO) As Long*

Public Declare PtrSafe Function SHGetPathFromIDList Lib "shell32.dll" (ByVal pidList As Long, ByVal lpBuffer As String) As Long

'corrected
Public Declare PtrSafe Function SHGetSpecialFolderLocation Lib "shell32.dll" _
(ByVal hwndOwner As Long, ByVal nFolder As Long, ByRef pidl As Long) As Long



Private Type PROCESS_INFORMATION
hProcess As Long
hThread As Long
dwProcessID As Long
dwThreadId As Long
End Type


Private Declare PtrSafe Function WaitForSingleObject Lib "kernel32" (ByVal _
hHandle As Long, ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function CreateProcessA Lib "kernel32" (ByVal _
lpApplicationName As Long, ByVal lpCommandLine As String, ByVal _
lpProcessAttributes As Long, ByVal lpThreadAttributes As Long, _
ByVal bInheritHandles As Long, ByVal dwCreationFlags As Long, _
ByVal lpEnvironment As Long, ByVal lpCurrentDirectory As Long, _
lpStartupInfo As STARTUPINFO, lpProcessInformation As _
PROCESS_INFORMATION) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" (ByVal _
hObject As Long) As Long


Private Type FILETIME ' 8 Bytes
dwLowDateTime As Long
dwHighDateTime As Long
End Type
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're missing a `Type` enumeration for the `BROWSEINFO`, see here for example:

http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/apideclarations.asp

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Private Type BROWSEINFO
        hOwner As LongPtr
        pidlRoot As LongPtr
        pszDisplayName As String
        lpszTitle As String
        ulFlags As Long
        lpfn As LongPtr
        lParam As LongPtr
        iImage As Long
    End Type

    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SHBrowseForFolder Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "SHBrowseForFolderA" _
        (lpBrowseInfo As BROWSEINFO) As LongPtr
#Else
    Private Type BROWSEINFO
        hOwner As Long
        pidlRoot As Long
        pszDisplayName As String
        lpszTitle As String
        ulFlags As Long
        lpfn As Long
        lParam As Long
        iImage As Long
    End Type

    Private Declare Function SHBrowseForFolder Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "SHBrowseForFolderA" _
        (lpBrowseInfo As BROWSEINFO) As Long
#End If
Private Const BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS = &H1
```

Comment: Thanks!
That seems to help... now seems that there are a bunch of extra issues with converting this to what I need...I very new at this so I'm just trying to figure it out...
it now tells me that 
Call BrowseForFolder(dhcCSIdlDesktop, dhcBifReturnOnlyFileSystemDirs, _
strPath, pszTitle:="Select an image folder: Criterium Photo Project")
compile error: variable not defined  for the dhcCSIdlDesktop part. All this was working just fine before.

Comment: I'm not really here to hold your hand through the debugging process... either this answered the original question or it did not...